# How to make a chat room for my website but cannot find working JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I am in the middle of making chat rooms for my website, but I have been stuck on one part for several days, which is finding the proper JavaScript to make the div refresh for the chat bubbles. 
I currently use ASP code for my website.

Any help with this? It would be greatly appreciated.

Also: It would be great if I could make a database chat-entry field without having to reload the entire page.

Here's a code snippet of what I have so far:

```
<div class="chatroomdiv">
chat bubbles here
</div>
<form action="chat_say.asp" method="post">
<input type="text" name="speech" />
<input type="submit" value="Say" />
</form>
```

Comment: You will need to post some sort of code example of what you are busy with.

Comment: Sorry about that, took me a minute to figure it out too as I'm new to the site. but I added it :P

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using ajax post, if you already using jquery, rather call the $.post() function.

Eg.

```
$.post( "chat_say.asp", { messge: $("#speech").val()})
  .done(function( data ) {
    $(".chatroomdiv").html(data);
 });
```

I have not tested this code at all and it should be treated as pseudo code.

The data variable will be the data you recieved from your asp page.

The jquery documentation is located here:
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/